# Is Hinduism brought by Aryans or Dravidians to India?

Tags: scripture, history

What is the origin of Hinduism? Is Hinduism brought by Aryans or Dravidians? Besides this there is a saying that North Indians are Aryans and South Indians are Dravidians. As per Saivism, Dravidians are dark complexioned worshipped Lord Shiva and Aryans are white complexion well built and  worshipped nature. If it is so Lord Narayna has so many divyadesas in south compared to North. Any scriptures supporting this?

Comment: @@Parthasarathy Raghavan - There is also a view, though a wrong one,  that Siva and Lakshmi were Aryan Gods.  Vishnu and Parvati are Dravidian Gods. The marriage between Siva and Parvati , Vishnu and Lakshmi is considered as a kind merger or confluence between the Aryans and Dravidians. Any way, the very theory of Aryan migration and invasion are myths propagated to divide Indians.

Comment: @Krishna - Parvathy is vushnu's sister; so shiva is  his brother-in-law. Now the saivites and vaishnavities are mixed.

Comment: @@Parthasarathy raghavan - Myth of Aryan Invasion by David frawley and articles by Stephen knapp and many other indologists prove the Aryan migration, invasion etc is myth. You can read them , if you are interested.

Comment: "Arya' means noble .It has nothing to do with skin color.Also as indians we should all know by now that the so called AIT is a fake one.

Comment: @Krishna--Thanks for suggesting--If I find time will definitely read  bcoz already vedaraman and naangam thiruvandadi are pending for reading.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18006/why-hinduism-did-not-get-propagated-to-entire-world/18014#18014

Comment: @ Parthasarathy Raghavan  What do you mean by "brought to"? It evolved as a way of life from ancient times. It was not packaged transported or spread from any single master or prophet. It evolved by social respect for opinions  and philosophies of truth and non-violence verified by its followers through their own mind and spirit.

Comment: To first approximation, it is a synthesis (mixture) of the religious tradition(s) the Aryans brought with them from Central Asia (this Aryan religion featuring, among many things, animal sacrifices for maintaining cosmic order) along with local Indian (including Dravidian, as well as others) traditions, worshipping animistic deities. Of course if you look deeper you'll find that like all religious traditions these traditions too have changed dramatically over the Vedic period. As for David Frawley, I would recommend you not read him, he's very un-careful and very angry, not a serious scholar

Comment: Also, just to get everyone up to speed: no one believes in the Aryan Invasion Theory anymore, not since the 19th century, except some people who live inside the minds of David Frawley and the like. The theory that Aryans migrated from Central Asia into South Asia during the 2nd millennium BCE and their descendants in India eventually "forgot" the migrations as claiming indigineity became politically convenient for kings (e.g. Guptas), that explains all the ancient DNA, modern DNA, Rgvedic hydronymy, and archaeological evidence FAR better than anything else, at all.

Answer (score 7):

Hinduism is eternal as it has no Aadi and No Anant. It is a set of governing principals of universe. So it is simple a philosophy of everything.

**Is Hinduism brought by Aryans or Dravidians?**
Philosophy is experienced or felt, just like we feel gravity, just like feel sun light. Who brought gravity and light? None, right? So everyone is a part of this philosophy inlcluding every living and non living beings.

**Besides this there is a saying that north Indians are Aryans and south Indians are dravidians.**
Aryans are noble people of any society. So, thus by hard work, intelligence and ability to "Shashtartha" one used to become noble or aryan.

Dravid shabda means "covered from three sides with sea water". So, this is the reason southern India is dravid, but if we consider its definition, then gujrat is also dravid, since it is also covered from 3 sides. Kindly have a look at the map.

**As per Saivism, dravidians are dak complexioned worshipped Lord shiva and Aryans are white complexion well built and worshipped nature.**

Philosophy has no connection with anyone's color, physique.It is a mental exercise. I am also dark skinned, and I am a north Indian. 
Krishna was also dark in color.

**If it is so Lord Narayna has so many divyadesas in south compared to north. Any scriptures supporting this?**

It is not true. We love Ram as a king and We love Krishna. They were also rulers. We also feel as emotions about Ram as you guys do. Why are you just separating us from you? We are you and you are we.

We all love you for your culture saving preservation.

Bharat or Bharatha has a sanskrit verb "Bha" and which is the root verb for other words like Anuvibha, prabha, prabhat and they are connected to light.

You know what Bharat means. It means The light of Param Aatma.
And we must all be happy that we share such a great civilization togetherness.

Read below image, how Bha verb has a meaning. Based on upsarg and pratyay, you get a meaning

[image]

Bha here means Light or reflection or light spectrum (rainbdow). But when we refer this word spiritually, this light does not mean actual sun light, but the parmatmaya: prakasham. The other part 'rata' means devoted to something.

Thus,
Bharat== devoted to paramatma or paramatma's light or simply knowledge**

knowlegde is very often used interchangeably with light.

ॐ असतो मा सद्गमय ।
तमसो मा ज्योतिर्गमय ।
मृत्योर्मा अमृतं गमय ।
ॐ शान्तिः शान्तिः शान्तिः ॥

This verse says tamso maa jyotirgamay.
jyoti here refers to knowledge only.

Now coming back to bharat, a land where people are seekers and seers of knowledge with devotion.When knowledge of person increases, we often say person's aura (tej) has increased. And all people do this, the land becomes a place of Aura yet another symbol of light.

Bharat== where all people are devoted to knowledge or paramatma's light.
Bharat= Land of Prakash (of Paramatma or of paramatma's knowledge).

Comment: Where did you find the meaning "Bharat = light of Paramatma"? I couldn't understand the relation with Paramatma in this word.

Comment: @yogesh Sanchitar Bharat means bharat desa. Where Paramatma is coming here?

Comment: Will give you explanation. I said what Bharat literally means. why it is not Ram desh.

Comment: Bharat doesn't literally mean light of Paramatma. Bharat is a distorted form in Hindi of Bharata Desha in Sanskrit. You can use @username to reply to a user who commented.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I asked for the relation between Paramatma in the Bharat. There is nothing as such in the dictionary you have added too. Bha means light but Bharata doesn't mean light of Parabrahman. Adding paramatma is your own definition guess. Land is named after Bharata, an emperor and not Rama's brother. You should use @usenae to ping a user. Psting a comment doesn't notify others.

Comment: So much fake etymology here it pains me!!! No, not even close. Bharata is from the bharata tribe name in the Rgveda, most likely derived from bhar- "to carry". And Dravida is from the tamil word Thamizh, maybe etymologizable as from *tam-pezhay "one's own speech", not from "three sides". three in Sanskrit is tri-, not dra-. Basic nirukta

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add a few points to@Yogesh Sanchihar's excellent answer.

1. Hinduism was never 'brought' to India by anyone. Hinduism is just a relatively new term for the Adi Sanatan Devi Devta Dharma (Sanatan Dharma ). Sanatan by itself means unending. Dharma is never made by anyone. It is our intrisnic duty, which stands independent of time and place. A person may discover his dharma or gain insight into it, but *no one ever creates or brings it*, for it is intrisnic to the very nature of the world of the Supreme Lord ( Parbramha ).
2. It follows that he origins of 'Hinduism' are timeless. In fact just as time proceeds in cycles without beginning or end, the Sanatan Dharma exists and shall continue to exist without beginning or end.
3. There is no such thing as an Aryan/Dravidian division. Yes, it is possible that people may speak languages of different families, just as they may eat fruits from different trees, but that does not alter the fact that we are all aspects of the Supreme Brahma, duty-bound to follow our dharma. Remember, that in the old texts and traditions, 'Arya' means a noble person, without any restriction of color or language. That the meaning was later changed to refer to linguistic families does not change this fact.
4. There are numerous Hindus, from all corners of the land, who have faith in Lords Shiva or Vishnu and who respect Nature. This is one of our age-old values and has nothing to do with Aryan or Dravidian language groups. Our traditions and scriptures belong equally to speakers of all languages.
5. It is said in the Vedas -
   " My eyes see all creatures as my friends." (Yajurved 36:10:18)
   Our Sages and Shastras never believed in any division between the North and the South; after all the North and South are North and South only within the united entity of Bharatvarsha.
6. Even modern studies have not unambiguously determined the origins of the supoosed groups. While the division hypothesis has been widely publicized due to historical and political reasons, there is ample scholarly evidence to show that the matter is far from settled. Work by scholars like Shrikant Talegari and Koenraad Elst is not widely accepted but it is more rigorous but *not* more politically motivated than the alternative. They have shown that the AIT is just a big scam.
7. Even mainstream social science has largely rejected the 'Aryan Invasion' and the supoosed Aryan-Dravidian divide in favour of more balanced and nuanced scenarios.

**TL;DR**

No one has ever discovered or brought Hinduism anywhere as it is a timeless philosophy to be realized by and to uplift the individual. The Aryan-Dravidian divide is also largely political and/or fictious. Therefore, the questions raised by you do not arise.

Comment: Hello. Visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/5212) and [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33/5212). Looks like you are answering every question philosophically and giving suggestions. Answers should be theoretically correct too. This is a historical question saying it is not brought by anyone would not be suffice.   Citations are important. I don't see any references in the answer for that.

Comment: @Devashish Kaushik Please go thru Sarvabhouma's comments.

Comment: @Devashish : Please tell the shloka number of Rigveda, where it says "My eyes see all creatures as my friends", as per your point number (5)

Comment: @zaxebo1 I have added the number (It was from the Yajurveda, btw - I had misremembered)